# ad block script for adsense ads is not working

Tags: adsense, adblock

i use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(window.google_render_ad)=="undefined") 
{
//document.getElementById('player-embed').innerHTML = '<center>text lablbabal)<br><img src=\"https://i.imgur.com/p7vHVHA.jpg\" /></center>';
}
</script>
```

but now is not working is blocking with or without adblock why??

and another script again is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain/advert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById("tester") == undefined) 
{ 
//document.getElementById('#disqus_thread').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('player-embed').innerHTML = '<center>text lalala<br><img src=\"https://i.imgur.com/p7vHVHA.jpg\" /></center>';
}
</script>
```

why is not working?? is the script wrong or what??

Comment: Try replacing the element with ID 'player-embed' with another element, and then loading your image into that. Adblock is probably disabling any modification to the original parent element.

Comment: after 1 day the script works again i don't know :) anyway can you suggest me better code or this is ok??

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes adblock can inject false show_ads.js which could trigger a defined variable 
window.google_render_ad == defined

so this is not a code issue but try [BlockAdBlock](http://blockadblock.com) they have good detection technology